# XQuery return text node if it contains given keyword

Tags: xpath, xquery

A test sample of my xml file is shown below:

test.xml

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <title>Link ISBN</title>
    <libx:libapp xmlns:libx="http://libx.org/xml/libx2" />
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <title>Link Something</title>
    <libx:module xmlns:libx="http://libx.org/xml/libx2" />
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Now, I want to write an xquery which will find all `<entry>` elements which have `<libx:libapp>` as a child. Then, for all such entries return the title if the title contains a given keyword (such as Link). So, in my example xml document the xquery should return "Link ISBN".

My sample xquery is shown below:

samplequery.xq (here doc_name is the xml file shown above and libapp_matchkey is a keyword such as 'Link')

```
declare namespace libx='http://libx.org/xml/libx2';
declare variable $doc_name as xs:string external;
declare variable $libpp_matchkey as xs:string external;
let $feeds_doc := doc($doc_name)

for $entry in $feeds_doc/feed/entry
   (: test whether entry has libx:libapp child and has "Link" in its title child :)
   where ($entry/libx:libapp and $entry/title/text()[contains(.,$libapp_matchkey)])
    return $entry/title/text()
```

This xquery is returning null instead of the expected result 'Link ISBN'. Why is that?

Comment: I've replaced `$food_doc` declaration as `/`, corrected the `$libapp_matchkey` typo, and successfully runned it with your input sample.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and natural one-liner solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to write an xquery which will
>   find all  elements which have
>    as a child. Then, for
>   all such entries return the title if
>   the title contains a given keyword
>   (such as Link).

**Just use**:

```
/*/entry[libx:libapp]/title[contains(.,'Link')]/text()
```

**Wrapping this XPath expression in XQuery we get**:

```
declare namespace libx='http://libx.org/xml/libx2';
/*/entry[libx:libapp]/title[contains(.,'Link')]/text()
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<feed> 
  <entry> 
    <title>Link ISBN</title> 
    <libx:libapp xmlns:libx="http://libx.org/xml/libx2" /> 
  </entry> 
  <entry> 
    <title>Link Something</title> 
    <libx:module xmlns:libx="http://libx.org/xml/libx2" /> 
  </entry> 
</feed>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Link ISBN
```

Comment: I see the following exception when I try this: for $entry in $feeds_doc/atom:feed/atom:entry return /*/$entry[libx:libapp]/title[contains(.,'Link')]/text() Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stopped at line 9, column 13: [XPDY0002] No context item set for 'root()'.

Comment: @sony: There isn't any `$entry` in my answer -- You may get any possible exception on anything that isn't my answer, but why are you reporting this as a comment here?

Comment: What does /* refer to ? I mean entry elements are inside <feed> element in the document. How are you referring to $feeds_doc/feed

Comment: @sony: I have edited my answer to help you arive at a complete XQuery -- you may just execute it and you will get the wanted result.

Comment: @sony: This is simple, basic XPath (and I seriously doubt that one can do XQuery without knowledge of XPath). `/*` selects the top element of any XML document (because in any well-formed XML document there must be a single top element). This is why we don't bother (and thus save time and space) to specify the name of the top element.

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks.My original document has various namespace elements including the root element. I forgot about the namespaces and got confused. Thanks again!

Comment: @sony: Glad this was useful. So, you can probably upvote + accept the answer? :)

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Conceptually good answer. Look at the input source you have posted.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for the findings. It appears that I copied and pasted from XSelerator instead of from oXygen :)  Fixed. now.

Comment: @sony It's common knowledge, what `/*` means, but it is inappropriate in this case.